# Error using Alamofire/SwiftyJSON in swift 4.0

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I got an error while programming in swift, and I can't get it fixed. The error: " Use of unresolved identifier 'dataFromNetworking' " in the "let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)" line. Google couldn't help me fix this problem. I think Alamofire or SwiftyJSON in swift 4.0 caused this problem.

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
println(json)

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they didn't cause the problem.

`JSON()` expects a data input, but you are passing nothing than a name.

You have to call Alamofire for creating data as a response of your server request and pass this response data to your JSON variable.

But you can't call a function inside a class definition anyways.

Please read the documentation of [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/README.md#response-json-handler), [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/README.md) and a guide to Swift/iOS programming.